# Host WCF in IIS

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

Hello all you smart people.

So, I've dared to make myself a WCF-service.
It works as is should, when i run it in the WCF testing utility.

But with the next step I've run into some troubles.
Hosting the WCF-service in IIS.

As said, the service works with the test utility.

My solution:
[image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/21380898/RealKursusSolution.PNG]

For hosting my service in IIS i created a folder called "HostIISTcp" as you can see in the solution, where i added my dll's and my pdb's under the "bin" folder. 
As i can understand, IIS cannot operate with an app.config file so i created a web.config file, where i simply copy/pasted from the app.config file in the class library.

The web.config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="MyWCFServices.RealKursusService.KursistService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MyWCFServices.RealKursusService.IKursistService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/MyWCFServices/RealKursusService/KursistService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I believe that the problem lays with the web.config file, and pardon me for being a newbie at this, but I've been googling like a crazy and i really cant find a proper solution.

To sum up:
Am I on the right track?
Are there another (better) solution for hosting wcf-services in IIS?
And if you could point out if anything is missing in the web.config file it would be great.

I'm using visual studio 2012, IIS 8 .net framework 4.5 and sitting in a leather-chair.

Comment: If I recall correctly, the trick was to create an svc file somehow, then drop that in an IIS application folder...

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113461/relationship-between-svc-files-and-wcf-projects

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: If you're using visual studio, you can just create a New Web Project on the IIS server that will generate the web.config you need and then you can add the web service through Add New Item.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, 
as far as i can understand svc-files are used prior to .net 4.0 and 4.0 and up are svc-less. 
So i would like to avoid puttin in a web-project in my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i figured it out.

By the way, sorry for the vauge question, i was pretty confuesd why my wcf service wouldnt be hosted.

I got the web.config working by with the following steps:

1. "Add new website" to solution (WCF-Service)
2. Delete the two servicefiles (Service.cs, IService.cs) because i'v allready my services defined in my other service library.
3. Add reference to my exsisting service-librarys.
4. Edit the service.svc file in my newly created website, to point at my exsisting service service

   ```
   <%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true"    Service="MyWCFServices.RealKursusService.KursistService" %>
   ```
5. Deleted the whole config in web.config on my new site.
6. Edit the web.config with "WCF Configuration" tool (right click on the web.config file)
   when using the WCF configuration tool it's pretty straight forward. Add a service and point it to your reference dll in the bin directory.

Then hosted the svc file in a new application under my default site in iis

Hope this can help someone

Comment: I strongly recommend against using a web site "project". Instead,  you should always use a web application project. Try the same thing, but this time use Add->New Project and choose WCF/WCF Service Application.

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain why ?

Comment: They are strange, unlike every other kind of project in Visual Studio - there's no project file, for instance. Everything else broken about them comes from that.